# keycloak flow to check user email against IDP and take them to that IDP

Tags: azure, keycloak, keycloak-gatekeeper

We have an app which has users in the keycloak database or in Azure Active Directory, the Azure AD is federated as an Open ID Connect IDP.

This all works fine but the issue is it requires our users to choose the logging in via Keycloak or Azure AD. The users don't log in frequently and it is simpler for the users to not have to remember if they are in Azure AD or in keycloak.

So the login flow we would like is:

1. An initial page which prompts the user for their email.
2. Depending on where the user is registered, the next page in the flow would be a Keycloak login page, or Azure AD login.

Is this type of flow feasible in Keycloak, or would we need to do this outside of Keycloak and then direct them an appropriate client in keycloak.